# How to show ListView in Tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I want to display ListView in Tab (after selecting this tab I want ListView to appear),so I have created Fragment class and placed ListView code in it.The main problem now is to pass fragment object to tabListener. Please, post here example, or even better show how to do that in my code. Anyway, any help will be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tabOne = actionBar.newTab().setText("One");
        ActionBar.Tab tabTwo = actionBar.newTab().setText("Two");


        tabOne.setTabListener(new tabListener());
        tabTwo.setTabListener(new tabListener());

        actionBar.addTab(tabOne);
        actionBar.addTab(tabTwo);   
        } 


    protected class tabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };

    public class FirstFragment extends ListFragment {
        private ArrayList<Cinemas> cinema;
        private CinemasAdapter cinemaAdapter;
        private ListView list;

          @Override
          public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            cinema = new Handler().handle(); 
            cinemaAdapter = new CinemasAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.movie_data_row, cinema);
            setListAdapter(cinemaAdapter);
          }

          @Override
          public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
              Cinemas movie = cinemaAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, More.class);
                intent.putExtra("Cinemas", movie);
                intent.putExtra("data", movie.getBitmap());

                Bundle translateBundle =
                      ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                      R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
              startActivity (intent, translateBundle);
          }
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open up the list inside the tabTwo, you will need to create an instance of the `FirstFragment` class and add it to your view when you select the tab. 
Inside `onTabSelected`,  create a new instance of `FirstFragment` if it isn't null, and add it to your view inside a container in your activity_main file. A container is a linear layout inside the view with the given amount of space that should be occupied by the fragment. In the case of a fullscreen fragment, the container is the root layout. You need only to specify an id to this layout. Once you create a new fragment, attach it by calling `transaction.attach();` The final code block should be similar to this:

```
/** this example assumes that the fragment
 * FirstFragment will be attached to tab 1
 * which is at position = 0, and SecondFragment
 * will be attached to tab 2, which is at 
 * position = 1. Also, the root layout of 
 * activity_main.xml has the id attribute of
 * fragment_container
 */

FirstFragment firstFragment;
SecondFragment secondFragment;

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:
        if (firstFragment == null) {
            firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,
                    firstFragment, "FIRST");

        } else {
            transaction.attach(firstFragment);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (secondFragment == null) {
            secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment, "SECOND");
        } else {
            transaction.attach(secondFragment);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to do what you've suggested but app crashed with this error (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView) What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @AvanJogia Did you get it working? It sounds like your error is one occurring with your ListFragment class specifically, not with how it is attached to the activity. Check out the class  to ensure it is working properly and tell me how it goes.

Comment: cant we do it dynamically?